# Getting only one result for a "football matchup" per team per week

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm putting together a new project, and one of the things I need to do is get the results of a Fake Football (American) match.  I'm doing this in php and mysql, utilizing CodeIgniter as my framework.  My dbfiddle is as follows:

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5Q7QezddpNEGabaia2w5FQ/0

Now, as you can see, each team has an entry for home_team_id and away_team_id.  What I would like to do is have a query that gets only ONE result for each team (regardless if they are home or away).  I'd rather not programmatically process this data if I don't have to.

The results should be something along the lines of the following:

```
SELECT week, home_team_id, away_team_id, 
    my_score, their_score, 
    a.team_name as home_team, b.team_name as away_team 
FROM nfl_user_matchups nm 
LEFT JOIN user_teams a ON nm.home_team_id = a.user_teams_id 
LEFT JOIN user_teams b ON nm.away_team_id = b.user_teams_id 
WHERE week = 1
```

Expected Final Data would be something like this (my_score would be home_team_id score, their_score would be away_team_id score):

```
+------+--------------+--------------+----------+-------------+
| week | home_team_id | away_team_id | my_score | their_score |
+------+--------------+--------------+----------+-------------+
| 1    | 3            | 9            | 112      | 144         |
+------+--------------+--------------+----------+-------------+
| 1    | 7            | 2            | 85       | 96          |
+------+--------------+--------------+----------+-------------+
| 1    | 1            | 6            | 111      | 114         |
+------+--------------+--------------+----------+-------------+
| 1    | 4            | 5            | 99       | 125         |
+------+--------------+--------------+----------+-------------+
| 1    | 8            | 10           | 140      | 122         |
+------+--------------+--------------+----------+-------------+
```

Comment: How do you translate your expected result using your database and query?

Comment: @tcadidot0 - What do you mean how do I translate my expected result?  Are you looking for an example of the final data?

Comment: Oh yes, I was thinking of what's the word to use and 'translate' just comes into mind. Could we see the example final data? thanks

Comment: @tcadidot0 - Added to original question.

Comment: So the last 5 of the records are the repeat of the first 5 but with the home_team_id and away_team_id in reverse?

Comment: That's correct.  But, it may not ALWAYS be the case where the first 5 and last 5 are reverse.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Your input data must correlated with your expected final result. Pls read the link Strawberry shared and edit the question accordingly, so that we can help you better. Anyways, the general idea is to `Group By Greatest(home_team_id, away_team_id), Least(home_team_id, away_team_id)`

Comment: Thanks for the links Strawberry, and I've updated accordingly, including a db_fiddle with legit data.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya - Your Group By is exactly what I needed.  Could you write an answer that explains why that works?  I'd like to give you credit with the proper answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem statement basically means that a pair of teams competing, *viz.*, `(1,2)` are to be treated same as `(2,1)`. One way to handle such requirements is to ensure that for any match between these two teams, we ensure that they are in the same order. So, basically we get the [`Least()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_least) team id value out of the two teams, and always put it in the first index; and the [`Greatest()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest) value always at the second (last) index. It is noteworthy that `Greatest()` is not same as `Max()`. `Max()` function computes maximum on a column; while `Greatest()` is *generally* used to compare values across a row.

Now, we can simply `GROUP BY` on this pair and compute the aggregates as desired. While determining home/away scores, you will need to use `CASE .. WHEN` expression to determine whether a particular row has home id the least, or away id:

```
SELECT 
  week, 
  LEAST(home_team_id, away_team_id) AS home_id, 
  GREATEST(home_team_id, away_team_id) AS away_id, 
  MAX(CASE 
      WHEN LEAST(home_team_id, away_team_id) = home_team_id 
      THEN my_score 
      ELSE their_score
      END) AS home_score,
  MAX(CASE 
      WHEN GREATEST(home_team_id, away_team_id) = away_team_id 
      THEN their_score 
      ELSE my_score
      END) AS away_score 
FROM nfl_user_matchups 
WHERE week = 1
GROUP BY
  week, 
  home_id, 
  away_id;
```

[**View on DB Fiddle**](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5Q7QezddpNEGabaia2w5FQ/2)